# Errors of approximation with Matlab

Tags: matlab, approximation

Can someone explain me why these code lines

```
    x = 0:0.001:1;
    find(x==0.9)
```

return 901, while these code lines

```
   x = 0:0.001:1.4;
   find(x==0.9)
```

return en empty matrix?

I know Matlab can involve in some approximation errors, but in this case it doesn't seem to make sense. The surprising thing is that if x goes from 0 to an integer number then Matlab represents each element of the vector without approximation errors. While if x goes from 0 to a decimal number, it doesn't work. Is there a reason why it happens?

Comment: This is happening due to floating point approximations. You can read more about it [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html)

Comment: The surprising thing is that if x goes from 0 to an integer number then Matlab represents each element of the vector without approximation errors. While if x goes from 0 to a decimal number, it doesn't work. Is there a reason why it happens?

Comment: @Alessandro Looks can be deceiving.  Try changing the data representation in MATLAB.  Do `format long g;` then display your data again.  Simply put, it happens due to the representation of the data for display in MATLAB.